# How can I make a CSS Grid act like a contained object?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to set up at 3x3 grid of quadratic cells in the middle of the screen. Each cell should contain one token image (stored at assets/images/...). Here is the important part: If I change the size of the browser window, the tokens should be resized, but not cropped, stretched or squeezed. All 9 tokens must remain visible on screen and retain their shapes as squares.

The equvalent of this is straightforward to accomplish with the backgound picture: background-image: url('assets/images/background.jpg'); background-size: contain;

Is there a similar function doing this with scc grids?

With the below code, I avoid the cells getting streched or squeezed, when I expand the screen horizontally, they still get cropped.

[grid with quadratic browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0aaX.jpg)
[grid with rectangular browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMO0e.jpg)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2%;
}

.square {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  color: #fff;
}

.square img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}

.square.fullImg {
  padding: 0;
}

.square.fullImg img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Sorcerer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Architect"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Warrior"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Healer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Merchant"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Necromancer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Alchemist"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Artisan"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Trickster"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a snippet for you. Please edit the question should you find the images I added not reflect your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting `aspect-ratio` for `.square`, use it on `.grid`, and ensure that its height does not exceed `100vh`:

```css
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto; /* This does the centering */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Remember to remove `<body>`'s default margin as well, if you haven't done so:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Try it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  margin: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

/* Original styles */

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 2%;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  color: #fff;
}

.square img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Sorcerer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Architect"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Warrior"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Healer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Merchant"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Necromancer"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Alchemist"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Artisan"></div>
  <div class="square"><img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Trickster"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi InSync.
That worked wonders. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @ErlendKK If you have found an answer that works for you (I'm just saying this generally, definitely not because I want to gain reps :P), it's good practice to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, its the first time I post here. I accepted it now.